# My Webscrape program isn't writing onto a csv file, yet its printing the data to the shell

Tags: python, web-scraping

***As mentioned in the title, the program isn't writing all the data into the .csv file. (it writes one line in one block.) it also doesn't spread out the data over multiple blocks***

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

   my_url="https://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html_from=R40&_nkw=switch&_sacat=0&_pgn=1"

#Open Collection

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close

#html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs each products
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",  {"class" : "s-item__wrapper clearfix"}) [1:]
```

***This is some of the file code***

```
filename = "EbayWebscraping.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "product_name, quality, price\n"

f.write( headers)

for container in containers:

    title_container = container.findAll('h3', {'class' : 's-item__title'} )
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    quality_container = container.findAll('span', {'class' : 'SECONDARY_INFO'})
    quality = quality_container[0].text

    price_container = container.findAll('span', {'class' : 's-item__price'})
    price = price_container[0].text



    print('Product: ' + product_name)
    print('Quality: ' + str(quality_container))
    print('Price: ' + price)
```

***Here is some of the file code***

```
    with open ('EbayWebscraping.cvs', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:

        f.write(product_name +"," + quality +","+ price+ "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: There is a typo in 3rd code, it should be `EbayWebscraping.csv`

Comment: @PCM i fixed that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Use a module like `CSV` or `pandas`. Use the CSV module, it is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
import csv
filename = "EbayWebscraping.csv"
f = open(filename, "w",encoding="utf-8",newline ='\n') # I changed this to '\n'

headers = ['product_name', 'quality', 'price']
csv_writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
csv_writer.writerow(headers)
```

Under for loop -

```
for container in containers:
    ...
    print('Product: ' + product_name)
    print('Quality: ' + str(quality_container))
    print('Price: ' + price)
```

After print statements -

```
    csv_writer.writerow([product_name,quality,price])
```

**Note- CSV Writer takes list as arguments. So write the product_name etc. etc. as a list**

Edit - I removed the ''. It should work now. And also added encoding.

Comment: i tried this and got an error. 'ValueError: illegal newline value:  '

Comment: It no longer shows up with an error, but now it only writes 'quality, price, product_name' in all the rows in the csv file

Comment: Got a weird error. 'return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u26f4' in position 90: character maps to <undefined>'. it linked back to this '    csv_writer.writerow([product_name, quality, price])'

Comment: Writing to a csv file usually differs from people to people.

Comment: Oh well,  ill try and figure something out. thanks for the help

Comment: Look at this edit, now it will surely work

Comment: You are bloody amazing. It finally works. thankyou

Comment: As I said, in mine, it works without adding encoding etc.. But it differs from each